# Are there any situations (e.g. failures) when browser clears cookies on its own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, nginx, cookies, browser

We have two sites with different *subdomains*. Sometimes our employees lose their cookies (they are just gone) on **both domains at the same time** so they get logged out.

I don't really see how our app can be responsible, because we have different server configurations (and for each site there're multiple servers btw). I guess only nginx versions (1.10.3) are the same. Plus this does not explain why do they get logged out on both sites at the same time.

If it helps, we use rails (3/5), unicorn (4.8.3/5.3.0), on older app sessions are stored in redis and in the new one in cookies.

So I wonder maybe there're some browser (security) policies when it clears cookies. Maybe on some ssl connection error, ip changes or whatever.

I understand that this is not definitive problem description but it seems like magic to us atm so I hope that someone encountered something like this.

P.S. btw we tried to ask one of our employees to use firefox instead of Chrome (that is used by all of them) but it does not seem to be making any difference (he wasnt logged out for a week but then he was like every 20 minutes)

Comment: Did you check the living time of cookie? Maybe your app just sets the cookie's `expires` to 20 minutes.

Comment: @yeuem1vannam yeah, ofc we did it. it is not happening every 20 minutes. It's just random.